# How to plot the bar plots for each data frames in the list of data frames

Tags: r, list, ggplot2

I have a list of data frames as shown below. I want to plot the bar charts for each data frames, as range on x-axis and wt0 on the y-axis. When I am trying to run under loop it plotting the graph for last data frame.

```
    li
[[1]]
  varName  Range  wt0   wt1
1  var 1 (-Inf,-6]  858  7788
2  var 1  (-6,0.5] 1698 85194
3  var 1 (0.5,1.5] 2040 15240
4  var 1 (1.5,2.5] 1928  7815
5  var 1 (2.5,3.5] 1900  5228

[[2]]
   varName  Range  wt0   wt1
1 var 2 (-Inf,-6]  858  7788
2 var 2   (-6,-5]    3     6
3 var 2   (-5,-4]   57   196
4 var 2   (-4,-3]    5   162
5 var 2   (-3,-2] 4008 18285

[[3]]
   varName   Range   wt0   wt1
1  var 3  (-Inf,-6]   858  7788
2  var 3    (-6,-2]  3205 11246
3  var 3    (-2,-1]  2968 94972
4  var 3  (-1,12.5]  5741 17884
5  var 3 (12.5,Inf] 11267  8167

[[4]]
  varName  Range  wt0  wt1
1    var 4 (-Inf,-6]  858 7788
2    var 4   (-6,-2] 3487 2387
3    var 4   (-2,-1] 5049 3361
4    var 4  (-1,1.5] 3607 4081
5    var 4 (1.5,4.5] 2043 3699

    for (i in 1:4){
    c <- li[[i]]
    p<- ggplot(c) +
      geom_bar(aes(x=c$Range, y=c$wt0), stat = "identity")
    }
```

Comment: Loop over the list or just map the list to the `ggplot` function. What is this trying to do? `li[[i]]`? It is above your for loop and there is no other instance of i. Plus using `c` as a variable name is not a very good option although it doesn't matter that much.

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example using dput()?

Comment: Move  `c <- li[[i]]` as first line in loop and add `print(p)` as last line in loop. Finally, replace all `$` from `aes` for appropriate name of columns `Range != binRange`.

Comment: @NelsonGon even after looping over the list, it shows the same result.

Comment: @Parfait  i did change the names and the results are still same I wanted to show all the plots in one page as we do in par(mfrow) but I am getting only the plot for last data frame.

Is it possile to have a button for selection of data frame from the list ?

Comment: Consider combining all data frames, `df <- do.call(rbind, li)`, and run `facet_wrap` without looping.

Comment: @Parfait This is working but I am not getting good chart as x axis is same on all the plots where as in my Range column its different for all the data frames

Comment: Look into *scales* argument of [facet_wrap](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/3.2.1/topics/facet_wrap), allowing x or y or both to vary.

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of @NelsonGon first comment you can map over your list of data frames:

`myPlots <- purrr::map(li, ~ggplot(.x, aes(x = Range, y = wt0)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity"))`

This will give you a list of ggplot objects. You can either print them by index `print(myPlots[[1]])` or you can iterate all of them:

`purrr::walk(myPlots, print)`

If you're in RStudio, it may only show the last plot, but in the upper left corner of the viewer pane there are arrows that can be used to navigate through the printed plots.